# birational map dominant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've run across a theorem stating that a birational map f : w -> w is dominant. birational means there is another rational map g : w -> v such that the compositions of f and g are identity maps. 
could anyone tell me how to show that a birational map is dominant?

Comment: Hint if $W$ and $V$ are varieties: Try showing that a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is dominant if and only if there exist open subsets $U, U'$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively such that $f : U \rightarrow U'$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, how do you define the composition if $f$ isn't dominant?

Comment: For any students of algebraic geometry, coming across this question like I did, a birational map is *dominant by definition*. In order for the composition of rational maps $\psi\circ\varphi$ to be defined anywhere at all, the map $\varphi$ must be dominant. So, if $f$ is birational with inverse $g$, in order for both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ to be defined somewhere, *both $f$ and $g$* must be dominant.